# conversion of word file into tex file

Tags: ms-word, doc, tex, mathtype

I need to convert my manuscript which is in word .doc format with math type equations into latex file. The problem is that majority of convertors do not handle with math type equations. How can I deal with that. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried to convert the equations first -- while they're still in Word? MathType will do that. If it's a long document, we recommend working on small sections of it, rather than the entire document at once (5-10 pages at a time). Use the Convert Equations command on the MathType tab in Word (or the MathType menu in Word 2011 for Mac). Choose the "LaTeX 2.09" or "AMS-LaTeX" translator and click Convert. Then use whatever other conversion tool you're using to convert the document into LaTeX.